# Storing pulses, then releasing them on trigger

Tags: spi, digital-communications, pulse

I have a BeagleBoneBlack microcontroller that can generate pulses and clock for SPI.  These pulses have rise times of a few tens of nanoseconds, which is nice.

Unforunately, the BeagleBone is 'slow': when it receives an interrupt, it takes several ms to then process and send along the pulses and clock signal.

What I'd like to do is use the BeagleBone to generate the pulses beforehand; they would then be 'stored' in a much faster device. When externally triggered, the faster device simply outputs these pulses. Ideally, this device would respond in the microsecond or nanosecond range. It needs two channels: one for the MOSI SPI line, and one for the SPI CLK. They would need to be synced together.

So, how can I do this? Must I deal with an FPGA (I have little /no experience with this)? If so, is there some breakout board I can use? Or is there some simpler way?

Comment: Why not use a small MCU for this?

Comment: Can you expand on that? The beaglebone is a microcontroller already... The problem is its latency.

Comment: Yes, because it's running an OS. Use something that doesn't have/need an OS.

Comment: BBB has two 200MHz 32-bit PRU co-processors that can make up for the non-realtime O/S.

Comment: Spehro has it; see http://www.element14.com/community/community/designcenter/single-board-computers/next-gen_beaglebone/blog/2013/05/22/bbb--working-with-the-pru-icssprussv2 : a bit fiddly from the software side, but designed for exactly this purpose.